# Underscores in VIM Abbreviation

Tags: vim, abbreviation

I am trying to set this as my abbreviation:

```
ab dump_var var_dump
```

but I am getting an error whenever I try to open VIM. E474: Invalid argument.  In my vimrc (above the abbreviation) I have the _ set to a word boundary with:

```
set iskeyword-=_
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
set iskeyword-=_
```

actually REMOVES the underscore as a valid keyword character. Don't modify the builtin `iskeyword` and it should work fine.

Comment: That works but now my w skips over _ characters.  I could always install the [camelcase plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905) I guess